# How to write a test case which will check parent component property?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Parent component:

```ts
export class PlayerListComponent {
  flag = false;
}
```

Child component:

```ts
export class PlayerAddComponent {
  @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  clkCancle() {
    this.notifyParent.emit(false);
    // this will set parent component property 'flag' to false.
  }
}
```

Now how can I write a test case in Jasmine spec file?

```ts
it('cancel button click should set flag to false', function () {
  // Act
  component.clkCancle();

  // Assert 
  // Since component do not have flag property. It will be set in parent while by Emitter.
  expect(???).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: *"this will set parent component property 'flag' to false"* - no it won't, that's not the *child's* job. The child just emits, which you can test for in the child unit tests; it's up to the *parent* to respond to that as appropriate. If you want to test the two components together, declare *both* in a `TestBed` and instantiate the parent.

Comment: You create a component, in your test, that has a template like `<player-add (notifyParent)="flag = $event"></player-add>`, and you test that, when clicking the cancel button, the component's flag is indeed set to false. Or you use the actual parent component in your test, if you want to test the integration of the parent and its child.

Comment: I have written my spec file for child component and used below html in parent component to bind it.

       <app-addplayer *ngIf="flag"  [playermodel]='selectedPlayer' (notifyParent)="getFlag($event)">
    </app-addplayer>

Comment: *"I have written my spec file for child component"* - then, as above, you should just test that the value is being emitted. It's not the child's problem what happens as a result of that.

Comment: @KiranChuahan did my answer help? Do you still have a problem?

Answer (score -5):

To test two components together, you have to load both in the same `TestBed`. For example:

```ts
describe('component interaction', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PlayerListComponent>;
  let component: PlayerListComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PlayerListComponent, PlayerAddComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PlayerListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should set the parent flag when the child method is called', () => {
    // Arrange
    const child: PlayerAddComponent = fixture.debugElement
      .query(By.directive(PlayerAddComponent))
      .componentInstance;

    // Act
    child.clkCancle();  // ...Cancel?
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Assert
    expect(component.flag).toBe(false, 'parent flag should be set');
  }
});
```

Otherwise, you should just test that the child emits at the right time, because it shouldn't be part of the child's responsibility what happens as a result of that (this behaviour could change without the child being changed, or be different depending on where the child is used):

```ts
it('should emit when the method is called', done => {
  component.clkCancle();  // here component is PlayerAddComponent

  component.notifyParent.subscribe(flag => {
    expect(flag).toBe(false, 'should emit false');
    done();
  });
});
```

Note that, in both cases, I would recommend testing that this happens *when you click on a button*, using e.g. `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('...').click();`, rather than when the method is called; this helps to separate the **behaviour** from the **implementation**, allowing you to rename the internal methods without needing to update the tests.